# Remove Duplicates But Leave One Row For Each

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

ONBackup Table:

```
Contract    FromDate    Invoice     Data
232         12/12/2017  123
232         14/02/2018  123
232         15/07/2018  123
232         14/02/2017  676
311         12/12/2017  881
```

There are lots of "duplicate" rows, a duplicate to me is where the Invoice numbers are the same, ie the other fields can be different.

The table has 1.4 million rows (and around a million duplicates), so not sure if the below would work or not as I am getting bored waiting for 3 hours and counting, it must be more CPU hungry than I though.

```
DELETE FROM ONBackup
WHERE Invoice NOT IN
(
    SELECT MIN(Invoice)
    FROM ONBackup
    GROUP BY Invoice
)
```

Is there a quicker way of doing this that will work?

Comment: you want to delete the data where Invoice numbers are the same...

Comment: Yes, but leave 1 row with that invoice number, it doesn't matter which.

Comment: What's the reason for wanting to delete the data? Just curious...

Comment: I've joined two tables and got a load of duplicates due to my lack of knowledge re joins!

Comment: @davidjwest Maybe you don't have to delete anything. If you just need the unique invoice numbers from a table, then use a select distinct with a group by or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  DELETE A
FROM
(
  select  *,row_number() over (partition by invoice order by invoice)as rn from 
  table1
) A
WHERE A.rn > 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `row_number()` function :

```
delete b
from (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by b.invoice order by b.fromdate desc) as seq 
      from ONBackup b
     ) b
where seq > 1;
```

This leaves latest `fromdate` for each `invoice`s.

Answer (score 4):

I think a CTE is a good option here: (note that you must end the previous statement with a semi-colon).

```
WITH CTE AS 

(
  SELECT Invoice, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY INVOICE ORDER BY SELECT '1') AS RowNumb
  FROM ONBackup
)

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RowNumb > 1
```